# Не добавляються данные в базу Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Countries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="getForm.php" method="POST">
        <label for="country">Введите страну</label>
        <input type="text" name="country" size="15"><br>
        <label for="city">Введите город</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" size="15"><br>
        <label for="district">Введите район</label>
        <input type="text" name="district" size="15">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить в базу">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть обработчик:

```
<?php
    $country=$_POST['country'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $district=$_POST['district'];

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("countries");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");

    $s="INSERT INTO Country VALUES
    ('".$country."','".$city."','".$district."');";
    mysql_query($s);

    if($s){
        echo "Запись добавлена";
    } else {
        mysql_error();
    }

    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Как уже понятно, хочу, чтобы данные, введённые в форму, озаписывались в базу. При проверке функция echo выполняется, однако в базу ничего не записывается, ломаю голову...

Вот сама база:

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name_country  | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name_city     | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name_district | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Помогите разобраться :(

Comment: Обратите внимание, что расширение MySQL устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я могу сейчас ошибаться, но в формате запроса `INSERT INTO` в случае, если вы не указываете конкретно, какие поля должны быть заполнены - необходимо в `VALUES` указать значения абсолютно всех полей - включая primary key.
Иными словами, стоит запрос строить либо таким образом:

```
INSERT INTO Country VALUES(1, 'country', 'city', 'dist');
```

Либо таким

```
INSERT INTO Country (name_country, name_city, name_district) VALUES ('country', 'city', 'dist');
```

А еще меня всегда веселила комбинация условий "NOT NULL" и "DEFAULT NULL".